# Why is my regression line below all of my regression points?

Tags: python, regression, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program to find the regression line with given points in "turtle graphics". Each x and y values are in a list called "nums" (x values are even numbered indexes and y odds). When running my program, the regression points are accurate. However the regression line itself, is below each regression point. Note: Regular points are of blue color, and regression green.

Here is my code:

```
# program for regression line
# f(x) = mx + b

nums = [39, 12, 54, 17, 68, 20, 70, 23, 79, 28, 100, 30]

import turtle

algebra = turtle.Turtle()

avg_x = 0
avg_y = 0

algebra.shape("turtle")

x = 0
y = 1
n = 0

len_nums = len(nums) / 2
len_nums = int(len_nums)

for i in range(len_nums):

    algebra.pencolor("white")
    algebra.goto(x = nums[x], y = nums[y])
    algebra.pencolor("blue")
    algebra.write(".", font = ("lemon", 20))
    x += 2
    y += 2
    n += 1
    avg_x += nums[x - 2]
    avg_y += nums[y - 2]

m = ((nums[0] * nums[1]) - (n * avg_x * avg_y)) / ((nums[0] ** 2) - (n * (avg_x ** 2)))

x = 0

regression_points = []

regression = turtle.Turtle()
regression.pencolor("dark green")

for i in range(len_nums):

    f_x = avg_y + (m * (nums[x] - avg_x))
    regression_points.append(nums[x])
    regression_points.append(f_x)
    regression.goto(regression_points[x], f_x)
    regression.write(".", font = ("lemon", 20))
    x += 2

algebra.hideturtle()
regression.hideturtle()

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being of a bent to check the math, my belief is the problem is due to the use of `write()` to plot points:

```
algebra.write(".", font = ("lemon", 20))
```

Fonts have a baseline and height that you would need to adjust for and it would still be questionable.  Instead, we can use `algebra.dot(2)` which doesn't have any such isues:

[image]

My rework of your code, which was a bit hard to follow in the form presented:

```
# program for regression line
# f(x) = mx + b

from turtle import Screen, Turtle

numbers = [39, 12, 54, 17, 68, 20, 70, 23, 79, 28, 100, 30]

iterator = iter(numbers)
points = [(x, next(iterator)) for x in iterator] # [(39, 12), (54, 17), ...]

n = len(points)

screen = Screen()

algebra = Turtle()
algebra.shape('turtle')

avg_x, avg_y = 0, 0

for x, y in points:
    algebra.pencolor('white')
    algebra.goto(x, y)
    algebra.pencolor('blue')
    algebra.dot(2)
    avg_x += x
    avg_y += y

x, y = points[0]

m = (x * y - n * avg_x * avg_y) / (x ** 2 - n * avg_x ** 2)

regression_points = []

regression = Turtle()
regression.pencolor('dark green')

for x, _ in points:
    f_x = avg_y + m * (x - avg_x)
    regression_point = (x, f_x)
    regression.goto(regression_point)
    regression_points.append(regression_point)
    regression.dot(2)

algebra.hideturtle()
regression.hideturtle()

screen.mainloop()
```

You'll want to verify that I didn't mess anything up of a mathematical nature as there were significant syntax changes made.